# Need to convert json key-value pairs to standard array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, key-value

I'm interperting a json string into a variable using jquery's parseJSON() function. The problem is, it's turning my data into an object instead of a 2d array. Eg,

```
myData = $.parse(JSON(data));
myData.name// = "Bob"
```

The problem is, "name" is not supposed to be a **key** (assuming that is the correct term). Instead, it should be:

```
myData[0] // = "name"
myData[1] // = "Bob"
```

How would I convert this? Or is there a different method than using a for loop to walk through the index of an array (but still be able to access both key and value as a string, as you would in a 2d array).

EDIT: This is some json that is in use (Note it's MUCH longer). This is what is given for "data"

```
{"feat_3":"4356","feat_4":"45","feat_5":"564","feat_6":"7566"}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you fill `data`

Comment: Added a snippet of json, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: It seems a bit of an odd thing to do, if you don't mind my saying. Why create a flat array with both the keys and their values?

Comment: where is bob then? because it would be like feat_3 could be bob instead of 4356

Comment: Yeah, I used your example rather than moving it to a "flat array" which makes much more sense.

Comment: @Teun, in that example bob it would have been {"name":"Bob"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've deserialized the data (e.g., you have `myData`, which is an object), you can loop through its keys using [`for..in`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4), and then build up an array that combines keys and values:

```
var myData, dataArray, key;
myData = $.parse(JSON(data));
dataArray = [];
for (key in myData) {
    dataArray.push(key);         // Push the key on the array
    dataArray.push(myData[key]); // Push the key's value on the array
}
```

Since `myData` is the result of deserializing the JSON in `data`, we know that `myData` is a generic object (e.g., just a `{}` as opposed to a `new Foo` or something like that), so we don't even need `hasOwnProperty`. If we didn't know that, and we only wanted to enumerate `myData`'s **own** keys and values, we would add a [`hasOwnProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) check:

```
var myData, dataArray, key;
myData = $.parse(JSON(data));
dataArray = [];
for (key in myData) {
    if (myData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        dataArray.push(key);         // Push the key on the array
        dataArray.push(myData[key]); // Push the key's value on the array
    }
}
```

There's no reason to do that in your case, unless someone has been mucking about with `Object.prototype` (in which case, take them behind the woodshed, give them a severe hiding, and then have them write "I will not muck about with `Object.prototype` several hundred times on the chalkboard), but whenever you use `for..in`, it's always good to stop and think whether A) The object is guaranteed to be vanilla, and B) If not, do you want only its own properties, or do you also want ones it inherits?

Comment: The first code block worked golden. The way it works out, I don't even need to move them to a new array. I can just assign the data in that loop itself. Wonderful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $.parse(JSON({"feat_3":"4356","feat_4":"45","feat_5":"564","feat_6":"7566"}));

var arr = [];

for( var i in data ) { 
  if( data.hasOwnProperty( i ) ){ 
    arr.push( i,  data[i] );
  }
}
```

Array will be :

```
["feat_3", "4356", "feat_4", "45", "feat_5", "564", "feat_6", "7566"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found TJ's solution to be a better solution than converting to 2d arrays like I had originally planned.

Comment: Corrected. Into `push` method you can apply more than one argument which will filled out an array