# How to implement unique key value set in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for elegant way to implement unique key value set in javascript,

I have an object that looks like the following:

```
{
    "name" : "admin",
    "type" : "users",
    "id" : "53cf50b32508adc39b0cc566"
},
{
    "name" : "admin2",
    "type" : "users",
    "id" : "53cf50b32508adc39b0cc566"
}
```

i want to create array / set that will have id as the key and name,type as the values.

the set must be unique!

the result should by

```
array : [53cf50b32508adc39b0cc566 : {"name" : "admin2","type" : "users"}]
```

the id should appear only once

any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785660/need-to-convert-json-key-value-pairs-to-standard-array

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia this is no unique

Comment: maybe you can use $.now() ?

Comment: @MuhammetArslan i need it in javascript i don't have jquery i'm using angularJs, but how can it help me?

Comment: You have a mongo id for uniqueness, what else do you need?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `var obj = {'53cf50b32508adc39b0cc566':{name: 'admin', type: 'users'}};`?

Comment: @Andy You may want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @impinball, well I couldn't really make sense of the question to be honest. That was a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: @Andy yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you're making is that you want to have an data structure that's not permitted in JavaScript:

```
array: [53cf50b32508adc39b0cc566 : {"name" : "admin2","type" : "users"}]
```

The above line makes no sense and will cause an error.

Assuming that you want to access your data by key, and your current data is in an array, all you need to do is create a new object and then loop over the parsed JSON, adding each object as a value to a new key id.

```
var out = {};
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  out[arr[i].id] = {
    name: arr[i].name,
    type: arr[i].type
  };
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xw6x/)

Comment: well i'm want a code that iterate the json and result in an array of this kind of object this was the meaning, i need it to be unique

Comment: @LiadLivnat note you should have included all the relevant information in your question the first time round.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that :

```
    var person = new Object();

var uid = createGuid();

person[uid] = { name : "admin" };


console.log(person);

    function createGuid(){
            var g = "0123456789abcdef".split("");
            var e = [];
            var h;
            for (var f = 0; f < 32; f++) {
                h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
                if (f == 16) {
                    e[f] = g[(h & 3) | 8]
                } else {
                    e[f] = g[h]
                }
            }
            e[12] = "4";
            return e.join("")
        }
```

Comment: sorry this is not what i mean, i need a unique list, not of guids, but go over an existing array and create unique list out of it.

Comment: `var a = [],person = new Object();


person = { name : "admin",type:"admin",id:"545421fdsfvdb" };
var id = person.id;
a[id] = [];
delete person.id
a[id].push(person);

console.log(a)

;`

is it ?