# convert php JSON Object to array

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i would like help in converting a json array into a normal array so i can use to make a chart in chartJs.

This is the data that i need to convert

```
[
  {
    car: "6.8889",
    eng: "4.6111",
    expec: "2.8889",
    expli: "4.3333",
    gsw: "7.0000",
    imp: "4.0000",
    iss: "9.6667",
    know: "9.3333",
    own: "11.8333",
    ques: "9.3333",
    too: "7.2222",
    wwod: "4.4444",
   __proto__: {},
  }
]
```

and i would like to convert it into:

```
[Log] ["4.0000", "9.6667", "4.6111", "9.3333", "11.8333", "9.3333", "2.8889", "4.4444", "4.3333", "7.2222", "7.0000", "6.8889"] (app.min.js, line 4)
```

i can do this manually like so:

```
for (_j = 0, _len1 = json3.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
    l = json3[_j];
    chartData2.push(l.imp, l.iss, l.eng, l.ques, l.own, l.know, l.expec, l.wwod, l.expli, l.too,l.gsw, l.car);
 }
```

however i have data which can have over 60 different values?
so i would like to just do *automatically*.

I've tried the following examples:

[Need to convert json key-value pairs to standard array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785660/need-to-convert-json-key-value-pairs-to-standard-array)
[Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Any he anyone can give would be awesome

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is '[ Object car: ... ' valid json ?

Comment: I think he has copied from the console, so it's showing some this like this, actually it's [{car: "6.8889" ...}]

Comment: Yes i copied straight from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this, using for each loop of object. Try this:-

```
var arr = [{
  car: "6.8889",
  eng: "4.6111",
  expec: "2.8889",
  expli: "4.3333",
  gsw: "7.0000",
  imp: "4.0000",
  iss: "9.6667",
  know: "9.3333",
  own: "11.8333",
  ques: "9.3333",
  too: "7.2222",
  wwod: "4.4444",
  __proto__: {}
 }
],
newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var key in arr[i]) {
    newArr.push(arr[i][key]);
   }
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Im gonna try this now.