# angular 2 - http get returns empty array

Tags: angular

My Component code:

```
products: Product[];
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(
        (products: Product[]) => {
            this.products = products;
        }
        );
}
```

My HTML Code:

```
                <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
                    <td>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/product-details', product.SKU]">{{ product.SKU }} </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/product-details', product.SKU]">{{ product.mrp }} </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

My Service Code:

```
getProducts() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product')
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const products = response.json().obj;

            let transformedMessages: Product[] = [];
            for (let product of products) {
              transformedMessages.push(new Product(product.SKU, product.mrp, 111, 111));
            }
            this.products = transformedMessages;
            return transformedMessages;

            return products;

        })
        .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

My Backend route:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    Product.find().exec(function (err, products) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Success',
            obj: products        //obj comes from here
        });
    });
});

Response:
{
"message": "Success",
"obj": [
{
"0": {
"SKU": "V2620151BR",
"Batch": "1",
"Folder Number": "85",
"MRP": "799",
"Size": "Free",
"Color": "Yellow",
},
```

My Backend Model Class:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    sku: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    mrp: { type: Number }
});
```

My Frontend Model:

```
export class Product {
    constructor(
        public SKU: string,
        public mrp: number,
        public selling_price: number,
        public current_inventory: number
    ) { }
}
```

[image]

My `http://localhost:3000/product` reutrns the json response correctly. But somehow in the HTML, when the page loads everything is empty.
I am only getting one value - `empty empty 111 111`

Most of the things are setup fine, I am not sure why the empty HTML when I get the response back from `http://localhost:3000/product`

Comment: share the format of response

Comment: this line will will be   let produts : Array<Product> = response.json(); thre is no need of obj

Comment: @PranayRana updated the question

Comment: @PranavCBalan updated the question

Comment: router.get() is this angular js 2 , never seen something like this

Comment: @PranayRana   : that's backend code.... I think Node.js

Comment: @PranayRana, thats nodejs, its my backend router

Comment: @good.learner :  did you checked response data in network tab

Comment: i suggest you debug code in map function ....thatis where you can check product objects returned by server code ...have you done that ? i use WEBAPI of microsoft and it works fine for me

Comment: @PranavCBalan, yes i am getting the response. sample response `{
"message": "Success",
"obj": [
{
"0": {
"SKU": "V2620151BR",
"MRP": "799"
},`

Comment: @good.learner :  then share the structure of `Product` class

Comment: provide your full response and product class structure

Comment: the problem seems with the response structure

Comment: for correct structure use : http://json2ts.com/ this helped me lot till now , and calss geneated working fine for me

Comment: updated the question further, the problem is here `for (let product of products) {`

Comment: your front end model is wrong you have to do somewhat like as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I better suggest make change in your backend code and try to return json string structure like

```
Response:
{
"message": "Success",
"obj": [
{
"ProductId": "0",
"SKU": "V2620151BR",
"Batch": "1",
"Folder Number": "85",
"MRP": "799",
"Size": "Free",
"Color": "Yellow",
},
}
```

that will resolve your issue , without not much code change in front end i.e. in angular part

---

if you are not getting sturcture of reponse properly I sugest you make use of this potal : http://json2ts.com/ which helps to convert json string to typscript object.

for this structure given by you :  `{ "0": { "SKU": "V2620151BR", "MRP": "799" }}`

this is typescript object got created.

```
declare module namespace {
    export interface ProductDetail{
        SKU: string;
        MRP: string;
    }

    export interface ProductRoot{
        productDetail: ProductDetail;
    }
}
```

if you have above kind of structure than  your code will be as below (i havent run code at my end but if there is any error please inform it should be like that only )

```
 getProducts() : Observable<Array<ProductDetail>>
     {
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product')
            .map((response: Response) => {
               debugger;//try to debug this part specially response returned 
                        //for server 
               let resproducts:Array<ProductRoot> = response.json().obj;

               let transformedMessages: ProductDetail[] = [];
              for (let product of resproducts) {
                 transformedMessages.push(new ProductDetail(product.productDetail.SKU, product.productDetail.mrp, 111, 111));
             }
              return transformedMessages;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

code in component

```
products: ProductDetail[];
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(
        (products: Product[]) => {
            this.products = products;
        }
        );
}
```

---

i suggest not to give same name to propeties , better keep name different - try below code

I am guessing here that your server code is returning json array of product

```
 getProducts() 
 {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product')
        .map((response: Response) => {
           debugger;//try to debug this part specially response returned 
                    //for server 
           let resproducts:Array<Product> = response.json();

           let transformedMessages: Product[] = [];
          for (let product of resproducts) {
             transformedMessages.push(new Product(product.SKU, product.mrp, 111, 111));
         }
          return transformedMessages;
    })
    .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

component code

```
products: Product[];
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(
           (res) => {
               this.products = res;
             }
        );
}
```

Comment: @good.learner - check my update .. i given you changed code as per you strucutre

Comment: @good.learner - try to change strucutre of you json returning from server i.e. backend as i suggested in my answer

Comment: check my question, i have attached an image of the response.

Comment: @good.learner -its difficult to create json out of it ... i see its dictionary kind of response "key-value" pair, i handled this kind of reponse in c# but not sure about typscript ...I suggest you just change your server response to simple structure..

Comment: @good.learner - you need to do like this for key-value pair if you are going with your current structure :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785660/need-to-convert-json-key-value-pairs-to-standard-array this is in jquery you have to do same in typescript

Comment: @good.learner - to understand you json data you get row data in you component without any kind of cast and use json piple i.e. {{data|json}} in template on response received

Comment: issues resolved, the problem was my response structure

Comment: @good.learner - that what i told you from beggining ....you have to change strucutre and things work for you......please upvote /accept if answer helped you ..else it ok

Answer (score 1):

You are subscribing to the empty array in your case, because the return is executed before getting all the data. That's why it is better to use Promise

```
return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {doSomething()});
```

If you want to keep your code, try to create an initial empty product and a real BehaviorSubject and emit the new value, then subscribe to this :

```
this.initialProduct = EMPTY_PRODUCT;

changeProduct: BehaviorSubject<Product or any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.initialProduct)
```

then just before the return `this.changeProduct.emit(product);`  and subscribe to the answer instead of the get function :
`this.changeProduct.subscribe((product) => {doSomething()};`